# Open excel file in web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, excel, vb.net, ms-office

How can I open excel file in a web application, I want to open excel file and allow user to edit and save, same as in MS Office. I am trying to open document files in my web application in .net. I can open and display pdf files, I also want to allow user to be able to open and edit excel and word files as an office experiance

Comment: Maybe start by picking a language out of that alphabet soup  you tagged your 'question' with.

Answer (score 1):

First, the Excel assembly must be added to the project. To do this you must add a reference to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library by going to the Project -> Add Reference  menu item. Go to the .NET tab of the dialog box that pops up and scroll down the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel list item. Double click on it and press OK. This adds the reference to your project. In the "using" section of your code, type

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Once the assembly is added to the project, a new application needs to be created:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
```

If you want to make Excel visible to the user you have to set the Visible property to true, the default is false.

```
excelApp.Visible = true;
```

The code above opens the Excel application, in order to use the application, you have to open a workbook by creating a Workbook object. You can open a new blank workbook by using the following code:

```
Excel.Workbook newWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
```

The preceding code opens a blank workbook with one sheet. The .Add method optionally takes a template object.  If the parameter is left blank, the default template will be used (like when you open Excel manually).

If you want to open an existing document for editing instead of creating a new one, you can use the following code to open the Workbook object:

```
   string workbookPath = "c:/SomeWorkBook.xls";
   Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath,
    0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
    true, false, 0, true, false, false);
```

The preceding code may need a little explanation. The workbookPath is of course the path to the existing spreadsheet that you want to open, and if using .NET 4.0 and the Office 2007 library (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library), it is the only parameter required. The rest of the excelApp.Workbooks.open parameters are a little less obvious. The following is the list of parameters that are passed to the function:

```
WorkBooks.open(string Filename, object UpdateLinks, object ReadOnly, object Format, 
object Password, object WriteResPassword, object ReadOnlyRecommend, object Origin, 
object Delimiter, object Editable, object Notify, object Converter, object AddToMru, 
object Local, object CorruptLoad )
```

To view the documentation on this function, follow the link to Microsoft’s website for further explanation of the function at: [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb179167%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Once the workbook is either created or opened, you must create a Sheets object that holds the Worksheets within the workbook. The following code will get all of the sheets in the workbook you previously opened.

```
Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
```

Now that you have the collection of Worksheets, you must get an individual sheet edit data within.

```
string currentSheet = "Sheet1";
Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);
```

In the preceding code, you have to type cast the excelSheets.get_Item(string) method because it returns an object. Now that you have the sheet you are ready to access individual cells with the following code:

```
     Excel.Range excelCell = 
    (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
```

The get_Range function must take two parameters. If the two parameters are equal, a single cell is selected; otherwise a range of cells will be selected. Again you have to type cast the return value of the method. Once you have a cell object, your can set its value using the .Value2 property, or use any of the other properties to manipulate ranges of cells.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, what I am trying is to allow user to edit excel file in web not open excel file separately. Like there is control available on telerik https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/spreadsheet/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Don't need all the functionalities, just user can edit some data

Comment: You mean the user is supposed to edit the file without seeing it?

Comment: yes. you can see it without open excel. All header, all rows and all columns is customized.

Answer (score 0):

Use Embed Code of Excel Sheet first you have to upload your excel sheet on One Drive and then Embed it the code will be given to you and use the iframe tag and paste it then you will view your excel sheet in your html page.
Example:

```
        <iframe width="402" height="346" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
            src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?resid=9A8DF70E172ABC38%21114&authkey=%21AAWX1h4bOSMBGY4&em=2&AllowTyping=True&ActiveCell='EventBudget-Seminar'!A1&wdHideGridlines=True&wdHideHeaders=True&wdDownloadButton=True&wdInConfigurator=True&wdInConfigurator=True&edesNext=false&ejss=false"></iframe>
```